# Pundit throws undefined method `user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pundit

I cannot restrict the Project model view to a owning user. Cannot figure this one out:

Error:

```
undefined method `user' for #<Project::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f94b25dd010>
```

project_policy.rb

```
class ProjectPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def show?
    user.present? && user == record.user
  end
end
```

Projects controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @pages = @project.pages
    authorize @projects
  end
```

If I remove the `user == record.user` all works fine

`application_policy` file is default

Project belongs to User
User has many Projects

`project.user` in the console works fine.

Comment: I suspect `authorize @projects`. You have `@project` not `@projects`.

Comment: Do you have `@projects` defined somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> undefined method `user' for Project::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f94b25dd010

Firstly, I'd assume that `@projects` is defined somewhere in your code using a `before_filter` and also I assume its returning a **collection of records**. If so then here is the issue

```
user.present? && user == record.user
```

Here the `record` in `record.user` will be a **collection of records** not a **single record**. So `record.user` just fails with that error.

Changing `authorize @projects` to `authorize @project` should solve your problem